# JavaScript: How can i populate table rows with the values in an array

Tags: javascript

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="99%" id="subAccTable">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <h2 align="left" class="pagetitle">Sub Accounts</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th width="10%" class="heading" align="center"><bean:message key="prompt.editVtierAttribute.action" /></th>
        <th align="center" class="heading"><bean:message key="report8.header.account" /></th>
        <th align="center" class="heading"><bean:message key="report8.header.homeDir" /></th>
        <th align="center" class="heading"><bean:message key="report8.header.primaryGroup" /></th>
        <th align="center" class="heading"><bean:message key="report8.header.addToGroup" /></th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="" class="<%=className%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="vtierId" value="<%=vtierId%>" />
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">
            <img name="subAccId" id="<%=subAccountUtil.getId().get(i)%>" onclick="deleteTableRow(this);" 
                 src="images/trashcan.gif" title="Delete SubAccount" border="0" class="clientActions" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">
            <input type="text" name="subAcc" value="<%= (String)subAccountUtil.getSubAccountName().get(i) %>" 
                   onchange="updateSubAccount(this);" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">
            <input type="text" name="subHomeDir" value="<%= (String)subAccountUtil.getSubAccountHomeDir().get(i) %>" 
                   onchange="updateSubAccount(this);" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">
            <input type="text" name="subPriGroup" value="<%= (String)subAccountUtil.getSubAccountPrimaryGroup().get(i) %>" 
                   onchange="updateSubAccount(this);" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">  </td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="<%=className%>">  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to populate the table rows here with the values in an array objArr which contains values like

`0)1234, ~, tedtds, tedtds etc.`

How can i populate my table columns (text boxes) with the values in this array ?

Comment: Mark  ! what is table2 here ? And how can i set the values of text boxes in my table's rows with this ?

Comment: With your answer i think it will create a new table and replace the already existing table with the new one rather than filling the text boxes in my table rows with the values in array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a string of html with a while or for all statement and then set the contents of a div with that html.

```
var table1 = "<table>"
var table3 = "</table>"

for (x in array1)
  {
  table2 = table2 + "<tr><td>" +array1[x] + "</td></tr>"
  }

var table4 = table1 + table2 + table3

var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv1')
mydiv1.innerHTML = table4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use one of the existing templating frameworks rather than trying to reinvent the wheel...

`jsrender` would work, though I've found `knockout` to be quicker and easier...

http://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

http://knockoutjs.com