# Chrome's and Firefox's validation failed

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//script 1 - making array
var tableDom = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var tr = tableDom.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var table = new Array(new Array(9), new Array(9), new Array(9)) ;
for (i=0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j=0; j<3; j++){
    var table[i][j] = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[j];
    }
}
function be(){
alert(table[0][0].innerHTML);//test
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="be();">
    <table border cellspacing="1px;" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>x
            <td>A
            <td>B
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1
            <td><input/>
            <td><input/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1
            <td><input/>
            <td><input/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome under 7 line is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined. And under 15 line "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

And in Firefox:

> tableDom is undefined
>
> var tr = tableDom.getElementsByTagName('tr');
>
> table is undefined
>
> alert(table[0][0].innerHTML);

Help me, please!
I don't now what's the problem.
I'm going to control the table value from JS, and I'm defining array by loop, I realized:

> var table[i][j] = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[j];

Comment: What do you need help with? Please be more specific

Comment: what do you want to do? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ?

Get all the contents in `<TR> <TD>` ?? or [Populate Tables/Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019241/javascript-how-can-i-populate-table-rows-with-the-values-in-an-array) ? or [Looping through tables, Collecting table elements, and/or Striped rows](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/dom-scripting/striped-tables.shtml)
 ?

**More Info. is really needed to answer your question.**